# Solr updating indexwriter does not affect search until the rebooting

Tags: java, solr, lucene, indexwriter

I did implement a Solr plugin for the purpose of updating some fields on Solr events (commit, optimize and etc.). My problem is the updated documents does not affect Solr search until I manually try to restart the Solr. Would you please take a look at my code and tell me what part caused this problem?

Regards.

```
    boolean success = false;
    NamedList response = new SimpleOrderedMap();
    keyword.init(searcher, params);
    BooleanQuery query = new BooleanQuery();
    for (String fieldName : keywordSourceFields) {
      TermQuery termQuery = new TermQuery(new Term(fieldName, "noval"));
      query.add(termQuery, Occur.MUST_NOT);
    }
    TermQuery termQuery = new TermQuery(new Term(keywordField, "noval"));
    query.add(termQuery, Occur.MUST);
    RefCounted<IndexWriter> iw = null;
    IndexWriter writer = null;
    try {
      TopDocs results = searcher.search(query, maxNumDocs);
      ScoreDoc[] hits = results.scoreDocs;
      iw = solrCoreState.getIndexWriter(core);
      writer = iw.get();
      FieldType type = new FieldType(StringField.TYPE_STORED);
      for (int i = 0; i < hits.length; i++) {
        Document document = searcher.doc(hits[i].doc);
        List<String> keywords = keyword.getKeywords(hits[i].doc);
        if (keywords.size() > 0) document.removeFields(keywordField);
        for (String word : keywords) {
          document.add(new Field(keywordField, word, type));
        }
        String uniqueKey = searcher.getSchema().getUniqueKeyField().getName();
        writer.updateDocument(new Term(uniqueKey, document.get(uniqueKey)),
            document);
      }
      response.add("Number of Selected Docs", results.totalHits);
      writer.commit();
    } catch (IOException | SyntaxError e) {
      throw new RuntimeException();
    } finally {
      if (iw != null) {
        iw.decref();
      }
    }
```

Comment: You need to reopen the searcher.

Comment: @user1071777 I know that reopening searcher is too costly. Is there any way to solve this problem without reopening the searcher? BTW, how can I reopen the searcher?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Solr, but in Lucene you should use [ControlledReadTimeReopenThread](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_2_1/core/org/apache/lucene/search/ControlledRealTimeReopenThread.html). It allows you to define how often the searcher is reopened. See also [link](http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2011/11/near-real-time-readers-with-lucenes.html) and [link](http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2011/06/lucenes-near-real-time-search-is-fast.html) (NRTManagerReopenThread was renamed)